# Python implementation of precomputed RBF kernel with Gram matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, scikit-learn, kernel, svm

Python has very limited information and `precomputed kernels` examples. `sklearn`
offers only one trivial example of `linear kernel`: [http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/module's/svm.html)

Here is the code for linear kernel:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

# import data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data                    
Y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='precomputed')

# Linear kernel
G_train = np.dot(X_train, X_train.T) 
clf.fit(G_train, y_train) 

G_test = np.dot(X_test, X_train.T)
y_pred = clf.predict(G_test)
```

This is not very helpful to further understand the implementation for other non-trivial kernels, such as, `RBF kernel` which would be:

```
K(X, X') = np.exp(divide(-cdist(X, X, 'euclidean), 2*np.std(X**2)))
```

How to do the same `train` and `test` split and implement `precomputed kernel` for `RBF`?

What if kernel gets more complicates which depends on other parameters which need to be computed in a separate function, say, for parameter `alpha >= 0`:

```
K(X, X') = alpha('some function depending on X_train, X_test')*np.exp(divide(-cdist(X, X, 'euclidean), 2*np.std(X**2)))
```

We need examples for such non-trivial kernels. I will appreciate any advise.

Answer (score 2):

We may write kernel pca manually. Let's start with polinomial kernel.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
from scipy.linalg import eigh
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

X_c, y_c = make_circles(n_samples=100, random_state=654)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

plt.scatter(X_c[y_c==0, 0], X_c[y_c==0, 1], color='red')
plt.scatter(X_c[y_c==1, 0], X_c[y_c==1, 1], color='blue')


plt.ylabel('y coordinate')
plt.xlabel('x coordinate')

plt.show()
```

Data:
[image: Data]

```
def degree_pca(X, gamma, degree, n_components):
    # Calculating kernel

    K = gamma*(X@X.T+1)**degree


    # Obtaining eigenvalues in descending order with corresponding
    # eigenvectors from the symmetric matrix.
    eigvals, eigvecs = eigh(K)

    # Obtaining the i eigenvectors that corresponds to the i highest eigenvalues.
    X_pc = np.column_stack((eigvecs[:,-i] for i in range(1,n_components+1)))

    return X_pc
```

Now transform the data and plot it

```
X_c1 = degree_pca(X_c, gamma=5, degree=2, n_components=2)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

plt.scatter(X_c1[y_c==0, 0], X_c1[y_c==0, 1], color='red')
plt.scatter(X_c1[y_c==1, 0], X_c1[y_c==1, 1], color='blue')


plt.ylabel('y coordinate')
plt.xlabel('x coordinate')

plt.show()
```

Linearly separable:
[image: Linearly separable]

Now dots are may be separated linearly.

Next let's write RBF kernel. For demonstration let's take moons.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, random_state=654)

plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

plt.scatter(X[y==0, 0], X[y==0, 1], color='red')
plt.scatter(X[y==1, 0], X[y==1, 1], color='blue')


plt.ylabel('y coordinate')
plt.xlabel('x coordinate')

plt.show()
```

Moons:
[image: Moons]

Kernel pca transformation:

```
def stepwise_kpca(X, gamma, n_components):
    """
    X: A MxN dataset as NumPy array where the samples are stored as rows (M), features as columns (N).
    gamma: coefficient for the RBF kernel.
    n_components: number of components to be returned.

    """
    # Calculating the squared Euclidean distances for every pair of points
    # in the MxN dimensional dataset.
    sq_dists = pdist(X, 'sqeuclidean')

    # Converting the pairwise distances into a symmetric MxM matrix.
    mat_sq_dists = squareform(sq_dists)

    K=np.exp(-gamma*mat_sq_dists)

    # Centering the symmetric NxN kernel matrix.
    N = K.shape[0]
    one_n = np.ones((N,N)) / N
    K = K - one_n.dot(K) - K.dot(one_n) + one_n.dot(K).dot(one_n)

    # Obtaining eigenvalues in descending order with corresponding
    # eigenvectors from the symmetric matrix.
    eigvals, eigvecs = eigh(K)

    # Obtaining the i eigenvectors that corresponds to the i highest eigenvalues.
    X_pc = np.column_stack((eigvecs[:,-i] for i in range(1,n_components+1)))

    return X_pc
```

Let's plot

```
X_4 = stepwise_kpca(X, gamma=15, n_components=2)

plt.scatter(X_4[y==0, 0], X_4[y==0, 1], color='red')
plt.scatter(X_4[y==1, 0], X_4[y==1, 1], color='blue')


plt.ylabel('y coordinate')
plt.xlabel('x coordinate')

plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: rbf pca]

Comment: thanks for your effort on Kernel PCA, but this is unrelated to my question.